# Code doesn't show any error but output doesn't change insertion sorting

Tags: c++, insertion-sort

If I take the input 3 numbers 9 6 3 the out is coming to be 6 6

I am trying to writing a code it doesn't  show any error but output change doesn't changes

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int arr[n];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        int current = arr[i];
        int j=i-1;
        while(arr[j]>current && j>=0){
            arr[j+1]=arr[i];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1]= current;
    }
    
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a debugger is? Also if your code does not show any error does not mean your code is working as intended

Comment: `arr[0]` is uninitialized and not populated. Is that intended?

Comment: `arr[j+1]=arr[i];` looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `arr` one less time than `n` when taking input as well as output. In your code, even if provide value 3 for `n` and then 9, 6, 3 as 3 numbers, `arr` is populated with only 9 and 6 in indices 1, 2. The index 0 contains garbage. This should be like below -

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
}
```

Same changes required for the output loop.

As for sorting part, in your code, the previous indices (i-1, i-2, ... etc) are all overwritten with the value of `arr[i]` until the `while` loop exits. Depending the garbage value in index 0 you may get different result.
The correct code will look like -

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    int current = arr[i];
    int j = i - 1;
    while(arr[j] > current && j >= 0) {
        arr[j+1] = arr[j]; // Notice the difference. Its arr[j] not arr[i] on right side
        j--;
    }
    arr[j+1] = current;
}
```

As @Tiger4Hire mentioned in the comments, it will be better to use `std::vector` instead of VLA.

Comment: Also the output loop also skips 0.  
Also "int arr[n];" is not standard C++ (but is okay in C). For standard C++,use std::vector<int> arr; arr.resize(n);

Comment: @Tiger4Hire, I have mentioned about the output part. As for usage of vector, I agree with you

Comment: Your answer answered the key issues - Misunderstanding array indexing, and the bug in the loop. I +1'ed your answer, because it felt like you gave good advice for what is a poorly expressed question. My comment was not meant as criticism, the three down votes for the question seemed unfair to me. It's a beginners question, but stack overflow should be accessible to all. So you deserve credit for providing good advice to a poorly worded question.